# Converter And ConvertAll alternative for UWP C#

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, converters, convertall

I am creating an app in UWP and actually noticed that the `System.Converter` and `Array.ConvertAll` functions doesn't exist in there... Why ? :/

Is there any way I could get them ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said, in UWP there is no System.Converter and Array.ConvertAll. You can however use the LINQ method Select to do the same work.

Comment: Small question, Could I just use a "Func<>" instead of "Converter<>", I guess it would do the same job right ?

Comment: Yes, you can use Func<> instead of Converter<>. The only difference between the two is that Converter<> specifies by its name that this is a delegate which will convert something to something else.

Comment: Okay great and btw, Select doesn't exist too, I just used: `(from x in arr select (float)x).ToArray()`.

Comment: What do you mean by "Select doesn't exist"? I tried the following:
    int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    float[] floatArr = arr.Select(x => (float)x).ToArray();

Comment: IDK, It just told me that Select is undefined. And I did have LINQ referenced.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Can someone explain how is this solution supposed to work? Im kind of new to this, an example would be nice

Comment: For anyone having the same issue in UWP, first make sure the using System.Linq is referenced then replace the ConvertAll with Select.